# Is it possible to store a For Next loop in an asp session object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, viewstate

I need to store the following code in an asp session object or viewstate.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstItems.Items.Count - 1
        txtcart.Text &= lstItems.Items.Item(i).ToString() & ""

    Next
```

I have this code on a content page on my ASP.Net site. I need to access it from my masterpage so i can print it to a textbox on the masterpage.

The control txtCart.text is on the masterpage and lstitems is not a drop down list.
It is an empty invisible list I am using to store items in, which I then call to a textbox as listboxes don't provide text wrapping.

Comment: What is your purpose with storing code in session or viewstate?

Comment: I am trying to store the code for the for loop i posted.

Comment: Yeah, we got that, but *why*?

Comment: I don't understand the concept of "storing code"... you can store objects, and those objects could contain methods/properties that could process data for you... but I simply do not understand what you want

Comment: @Mario I need to store it so i can call it from a masterpage to display it in a textbox as to my knowledge there is no way to directly call the values from the listbox to the masterpage from a content page and display them

Comment: Then that should be your question =)

Comment: I edited my original post to try and better reflect what i need to do. If it's not possible to do it this way does anybody know if there is some sort of method i can use?

Comment: Well, your content page can update the textbox on the master page.

Comment: @CMKanodem, i have been trying this too but i need the code to say something like
txtcart.text = the items placed in the list by the for loop

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @ashish, you cannot "store code" in a session variable, as there is no such concept (that I'm aware of).

However, based on your comment...

> I need to store it so i can call it from a masterpage to display it in a textbox as to my knowledge there is no way to directly call the values from the listbox to the masterpage from a content page and display them

You have many options: here are a couple...

Firstly is to create a public property of the master page, for example...

```
Public Function DoThis(Byval lstItems as DropDownList) as String
  Dim result as string = ""
  For i As Integer = 0 To lstItems.Items.Count - 1
   result &= lstItems.Items.Item(i).ToString() & ""
  Next
  return result
End Function
```

And then in your page call...

```
CType(Page.Master, MyMasterPageType).DoThis(lstItems)
```

---

Another option would be to...

- create a class with the method
- create an instance of the object
- store it in the session
- access the object from the session and call the method

Comment: Just editied my original post to clarify it is not a dropdownlist

Comment: @Max, it doesn't matter what it is... I'm showing you some concepts of being able to call code (without "storing" it in a session variable)

Comment: Sorry for being somewhat stupid about all this.
I am not experienced in ASP.Net and i've been trying to solve this issue for over 3 hours. My head is totally melted right now.

Answer (score 1):

noooo you cant do that..session or viewstate objects can store only varialbe values..